# connect to remote sql server with different windows credentials

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to connect to a remote sql server using management studio with windows credentials other than the current
login credentials?

Right now i remote desktop into the sql server machine and login with the windows credentials that I want to connect with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the application and choose "Run as different user".

If you are on Vista or Win7, you may need to look at [ShellRunAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361.aspx) to create the menu option in your windows shell.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative in Windows 7 is to use command prompt running as alternative user

```
runas /user:domain\username CMD
```

this will start command shell that you can use to launch SSMS application. This approach is also helpful because as long as that instance of "command prompt" is running, you can start and test different applications as they function under that user without having to retype the credentials